# bash coproc child-parent communication within subshell

Tags: bash

I want to execute something like the following script:

```
coproc test { ls; }
base64 <&${test[0]} | wc -l
```

But it fails, which has to do with [the](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html):

> Other than those created to execute command and process substitutions, the file descriptors are not available in subshells.

One way to work around this is:

```
coproc test { ls; }
out=$(cat<&${test[0]});
echo $out|base64| wc -l
```

Is there a way to achieve the same using pipes?

Comment: `{ base64 | wc -l; } <&$test`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
coproc test (ls)
wc -l < <(base64 <&"${test[0]}")
```